# cvc-elt.1 cannot find the declaration error from a built jar, works correctly however from eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I have a java program that I first had running in eclipse and it is working correcty when I load and parse an xml file.

I just built it as jar file and am running and now the same xml file  I am getting this error

cvc-elt.1 cannot find the declaration for a certain element.

I know my xml is good becuase it is the same file that worked in eclipse.

Is ther any special jar I need to include in my jar manifest so that the xml will parse correctly.

Thank you so much!

Comment: what's full stack trace?

Comment: I have GUI pop up window that just says the file did not load properly. It prints Line 2 cvc-elt.1 cannot find the declaration for a certain element    I don't have the full stack trace

Comment: I tried having the same jar files in the classpath of the manifest as are lncluded in eclipse. Eclipse does have bunch of the standard list of java jar files it includes for the language. That is the only different. Like rt.jar,etc

Comment: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Line 2: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'TnDBoard'.
        at dynamictnd.BoardDefinition$1.error(BoardDefinition.java:185)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at

Comment: There is the stack trace above I had to chop in lenght. If anybody needs the rest of it let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I needed to turn off validation in my code